# vim not showing me if I have modified the file

Tags: vim, terminal, editor, iterm

Suppose I open multiple tabs in vim, using `tabnew`. Now, if I modifiy a file in any of the tabs, vim shows me that I have modified the file by placing a `+` in front of the tab's title, which happens to be the file's name.

However, when I am editing a single file in vim in iTerm, then I don't see any visual indication to tell me that I have modified the file. Is there a way to get a visual indicator here just like when I open the file in a tab?

Comment: is there a filename and a  `+` at the bottom left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `:set laststatus=2` (see `:help status-line` for details). Vim shows the "file modified" status in the status line by default. If you don't see it in the status line check `statusline` variable. Probably `:set statusline+=%m` will be sufficient (see `:help 'statusline'`).

Comment: `set laststatus=2` put a status bar at the bottom of vim. But, when I modified the file, the status did not change. I was expecting that it would put a `+` in front of the filename in the status bar. But it did not.

Comment: @user2048925 Almost there, just read the [`:help statusline`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27statusline%27). Try to `set statusline=%m%f)`.

Comment: @user2048925 can you show output of `:verbose set statusline?` please?